# How to change the background color of a JSpinner dependent on the current edited content of the field?

Tags: java, swing, listener, jspinner

I have a GUI with a `JSpinner` using a `SpinnerNumberModel` using `double` values.

As soon as I change the content of the `Editor` of the `JSpinner`, I want the background to change to yellow (to show that the currently displayed value is not the one "saved" in the `JSpinner` respectively its `Model`.

If that content is not valid (e.g. out of the allowed range specified by my `SpinnerNumberModel` or a text as "abc") the background should change to red.

I tried to achieve what I want with a `FocusListener` already but yet have not been successful, also I am not sure if It could work anyway, as I need to check the content somewhere between focussing and defocussing.

I checked Tutorials for all `Listeners` that exist for `Swing` components, but could not find a right one that suits the job. ([here I informed myself](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html))

I am new to the concept of `Listeners` and would really appreciate any help that gets me closer to solving the problem but also helps generally understanding `Listeners` and how to use them in this context better!

**My really basic code example with the mentioned poor attempt using a focus listener:**

```
public class test implements FocusListener{

JFrame frame;

SpinnerNumberModel model;
JSpinner spinner;
JComponent comp;
JFormattedTextField field;

public test() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    model = new SpinnerNumberModel(0., 0., 100., 0.1);
    spinner = new JSpinner(model);
    comp = spinner.getEditor();
    field = (JFormattedTextField) comp.getComponent(0);
    field.addFocusListener(this);

    frame.getContentPane().add(spinner);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("defocus spinner")); //to have something to defocus when testing :)
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //when the values of the field and the spinner don't match, the field should get yellow
    if(!field.getValue().equals(spinner.getModel().getValue())) {
        field.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }
}

@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //if they match again, reset to white
            if(!field.getValue().equals(spinner.getModel().getValue())) {
                field.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
}
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 3) Why not change the border color of the spinner, or the color in an icon beside it? Am always cautious of changing the BG color in components that use colors for their own reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the fb, I'll fix the code example as soon as I found a solution for myself, already fixed the hanging bracket!
Stuff like that surely annoys seasoned users like you but are definitely big traps for newbies like me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fulfill the task with a combination of a `KeyListener`, a `DocumentListener` and a `FocusListener`. The solution might not be the easiest, but finally I coded sth. that works. Comments in the file appended should explain how I dealt with the problem.

I expanded the original task with a `CommaReplacingNumericDocumentFilter expands DocumentFilter` `class` that was not written by me, I got the code from my professor and edited it to my needs only. Now only *digits*, *minus* and *e*, *E* are accepted as entries in the `JSpinner`.
*Commas* are *replaced* *with* *dots* also.

**Code:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;


public class test implements DocumentListener, ChangeListener, KeyListener{
    boolean keyPressed;
    JFrame frame;   
    SpinnerNumberModel model;
    JSpinner spinner;
    JComponent comp;
    JFormattedTextField field;

public test() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    model = new SpinnerNumberModel(0., 0., 100000., .1);
    spinner = new JSpinner(model);

    //disable grouping for spinner
    JSpinner.NumberEditor editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(spinner);
    editor.getFormat().setGroupingUsed(false);
    spinner.setEditor(editor);

    comp = spinner.getEditor();
    field = (JFormattedTextField) comp.getComponent(0);
    field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
    field.addKeyListener(this);
    spinner.addChangeListener(this);

    frame.getContentPane().add(spinner);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    DocumentEventHandler(e);
}

@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    DocumentEventHandler(e);
}

@Override
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    DocumentEventHandler(e);
}

public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
{  
  try  
  {  
    double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
  {  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //to get the right format for double precision numbers
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    test test = new test();
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    System.out.println("valuechanged: " + spinner.getValue().toString());
    if(keyPressed) {
        field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
    keyPressed = false;
}

public void DocumentEventHandler(DocumentEvent e) {
    //as soon as update is inserted, set background to yellow
    if (keyPressed) {
        field.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);  

        //check if input is numeric and in bounds
        String text = field.getText();
        if (isNumeric(text)) {
            double value = Double.parseDouble(text);
            if (value < (Double)model.getMinimum() || value > (Double)model.getMaximum()) {
                field.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        }
        else { //set background to red
            field.setBackground(Color.RED);
        } 
    }

    keyPressed = false;

    //System.out.println(e.toString());
    //System.out.println("Text: " + field.getText());
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 /** If not done yet, replaces the DocumentFilter with one replacing commas by decimal points.
    *  This can't be done at the very beginning because the DocumentFilter would be changed to a
    *  javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter$DefaultDocumentFilter when setting up the JSpinner GUI. */
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
       PlainDocument document = (PlainDocument)(field.getDocument());
       if(!(document.getDocumentFilter() instanceof CommaReplacingNumericDocumentFilter))
           document.setDocumentFilter(new CommaReplacingNumericDocumentFilter());
       /*Tell the other handlers that a key has been pressed and the change in the document does
        * not come from using the JSpinner buttons or the MouseWheel.
        */
       keyPressed = true;
   }



}

/** A javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter that replaces commas to decimal points
 *  and ignores non-numeric characters except 'e' and 'E'. This is called before
 *  modi */
class CommaReplacingNumericDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr)
            throws BadLocationException {
    text = filter(text);
    if (text.length() > 0)
        super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attr);
}

@Override
public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
    AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
    text = filter(text);
    if (text.length() > 0)
        super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
}

String filter(String text) {
    return text.replace(',', '.').replaceAll("[^0-9eE.-]","");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A JSpinner uses a text field as the editor for the spinner

So, you can add a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` of the text field that is used as the editor.

Something like:

```
JTextField textField = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)spinner.getEditor()).getTextField());
textField.getDocument.addDocumentListener(...);
```

Then when text is added/removed a DocumentEvent will be generated and you can do your error checking. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Listener For Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the example provided following your link shows how to get the Source, Number of characters inserted and the Total Number of characters. As I need to interpret the inserted text, it would help me a lot if you could provide a short example of how to get inserted elements in a String for example. 

It seems that I have to use the `getChange(Elemente elem)` method of the Document event method, but I find it very confusing, examples I found [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent.ElementChange) didn't help me as well.

Comment: @Vito, Well your ultimate requirement is to change the background color of the text field, so you must have a reference to the text field. Then you can just use the getText() method to get the text and validate it. Or you can also get the text from the Document.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CaretListener` , here is a start:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.event.CaretEvent;
import javax.swing.event.CaretListener;

public class SpinerTest{

    JSpinner spinner;

    public SpinerTest() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        SpinnerNumberModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(0., 0., 100., 0.1);
        spinner = new JSpinner(model);
        setCaretListener();
        frame.getContentPane().add(spinner);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setCaretListener() {

        for(Component c : spinner.getEditor().getComponents()) {

            JFormattedTextField field =(JFormattedTextField) c;

            field.addCaretListener(new CaretListener(){
                @Override
                public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent ce) {

                    if (field.isEditValid()) {
                        //add aditional test as needed
                        System.out.println("valid Edit Entered " + field.getText());
                        field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                    else                {
                        System.out.println("Invalid Edit Entered" + field.getText());
                        field.setBackground(Color.PINK);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new SpinerTest();
    }
}
```